# print non-ASCII / symbolic characters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, unicode, symbols, printf

I'd like to have a statement that did:

```
my_angle = 1*pi;
fprintf('My angle is %.3f pi.\n',my_angle/pi);
```

but that produced `My angle is 1.000 pi`, instead of the *actual* π character.

I'm thinking some sort of use of Unicode...
I found some related things:

- [Page on Unicode pi](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03C0/index.htm)
- [Sort of related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014476/is-it-possible-to-print-unicode-text-or-characters-in-matlab)
- [Perhaps a more relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415767/write-unicode-strings-to-a-file-in-matlab)

Comment: It's not really similar to that SO question unless you're putting text on a plot. Are you writing to a file or just trying to print to the command window? Maybe see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415767/write-unicode-strings-to-a-file-in-matlab).

Comment: Just trying to print to the command window. I also saw that page while  I was searching, but lost it before forming this question. I've added to the question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `fprintf`, but [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) works – just leave off the semicolon:

```
sprintf('My angle is %.3f %c.\n',my_angle,char(960))
```

Or you can use [`disp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html):

```
disp(['My angle is ' num2str(my_angle,'%.3f') ' ' char(960) '.']);
```

Comment: While this should work on Linux, and maybe OSX, I don't think it will work on Windows.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: Not sure if it's a valid test, but on R2013a and OS X I changed my default character set (`feature('DefaultCharacterSet','Windows-1252')`) and these both still worked.

Comment: +1 Very helpful and inspiring. Even *within* the extended ASCII range, just think about `char(177)` for ± instead of `+/-`, or `char(215)` for × in your printouts. Thanks.

Comment: @s.bandara: With a bit of Unicode you can do [crazy things in Matlab](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/stackoverflow/05/diacritics.png). Displaying things in the command window is harder though.

Comment: Wow, you rendered those into an image matrix, or just `text` into axes?

Comment: Haha, now my only problem is my font (both Ubuntu and OSX MATLAB) doesn't include that character. 
Hmm....

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on your OS. On Windows Matlab uses the windows-1252 character set which is pretty limited. I think `char` with values greater than 255 you get nothing/squares. On Linux you can use full UTF8 character sets and can use `char` with any value you want.