# Reading polish characters with textscan in Matlab

Tags: matlab, encoding, special-characters, polish, iso-8859-2

I need to read text files with polish characters in it.

For example the ł.

I tried to set the right encoding for polish language:

```
fileID=fopen('Polish.lab','r','n','ISO-8859-2');
text=textscan(fileID,'%s');
celldisp(text)
```

but I still get wrong characters.

```
 text{1}{1} = Å
```

Comment: I think the problem is not about reading but about displaying. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845628/print-non-ascii-symbolic-characters-in-matlab) for solutions to that problem.

Comment: `feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8');` Did the trick for me.